# Differentiate scanning one char or multiple

Tags: c, char, scanf

I need to differentite scanning one char or multiple at once and confirm it by pressing enter(no CTRL+D).

```
    do{
        scanf(" %c%c", &letters[i],&temp);
        i++;
      }while(temp != '\n');
```

It works for one char, but when I input multiple char and press enter it, it waits for another enter. I need to figure it out by just pressing enter once.

Answer (score 1):

> Differentiate scanning one char or multiple

OP approach fails as `" "` consumes any whitespace, including `'\n'` and may not get caught as `temp`.

```
// Troublesome code
do {
  scanf(" %c%c", &letters[i],&temp);
  i++;
} while(temp != '\n');
```

---

Look for the `'\n'`.  Could do it character - by - character.

```
#define N 2
char letters[N]; 
size_t i = 0;
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {  // Loop until \n found
  if (i < sizeof letters) {                      // Save up to N characters.
    letter[i++] = ch;
  }
}

// Limit output with a precision                     v----------vvvvvvv 
printf("%zu characters entered: The first few are <%.*s>\n", i, (int) i, letters);
```

Comment: I used it in loop, first input with one char executed right, but second input with one char not. It output like non-printing character '▒'.

Comment: I am doing this for my school project. Hangman game, where u guess letters or u can try guess whole word at once